# Overriding anonymous class'es method in java

Tags: java, vaadin, anonymous

I would like to override getSortableContainerPropertyIds-method but I have no idea how to do it. There is a getContainerPropertyIds-method in IndexedContainer, but I have to re-implement it, because the default implementation doesn't give me everything I need.

```
IndexedContainer diagnosesContainer = new IndexedContainer()
    {
            @Override
            public Collection<?> getSortableContainerPropertyIds() {
                // Default implementation allows sorting only if the property
                // type can be cast to Comparable
                return getContainerPropertyIds();
            }
    };
```

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: You can replace the line "return getContainerPropertyIds()" with the code that does what you want to do. If this is not the case - please add more info on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically the case is that in Vaadin when using default implementation of getSortableContainerPropertyIds in Table container, it makes every column sortable in UI and I don't want that. https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/IndexedContainer.html#getSortableContainerPropertyIds()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the sorting for some of the columns, you could override the method similar to the following:

```
IndexedContainer diagnosesContainer = new IndexedContainer() { 

        @Override 
        public Collection<?> getSortableContainerPropertyIds() {
            Collection<?> propertyIds = getContainerPropertyIds();

            // Remove the ids that should not be sortable
            propertyIds.remove("propertyId");

            return propertyIds;
        } 
};
```

Whereas you remove the property ids of the columns you do not want to sort and only return the ids that should be sortable.